# Can I access Maven properties as variables in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I have a Maven project that derives the path to a native library using properties which can be set in local profiles. For example:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <environmentVariables>
            <LD_LIBRARY_PATH>${foo.libdir}</LD_LIBRARY_PATH>
          </environmentVariables>
          <fork>always</fork>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>foo-default</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <foo.libdir>/usr/local/lib</foo.libdir>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

When I'm working with this project in Eclipse using the [M2Eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/), I'd like to be able to set up run configurations that also reference this path in the same was (e.g., so I can run the Eclipse debugger on the project). Is there a way to access the Maven property from Eclipse, e.g., so that could set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the run configuration using a variable like `${maven_property:foo.libdir}`?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think so.

Your maven script could refer to environment variable that you could define in the environment tab of your [launch configuration](http://web.archive.org/web/20160314161203/http://vasanth.in/2008/01/29/eclipse-tip-specify-environment-variables-for-launched-applications)

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20160314161203im_/http://www.vasanth.in/content/binary/WindowsLiveWriter/EclipseTipSpecifyEnvironmentVariablesfor_E319/Eclipse%20Tip%20Environment%20Variables%20for%20Launched%20Applications_6b5b4a83-7394-4afe-9afd-ede3a20c37dd.png]

But the other way around (i.e. your configuration resolving at launch time some maven script property) is not, as far as I know, possible.